# How to make props safe in jsx like jinja2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, jinja2

My getServerSideProps returns a prop that has some HTML in it. I want it to be rendered as HTML, not plain text.
Suppose if my prop returns <h1>This</h1> I want it to be rendered as an actual h1 like

## This

not actual plain text is there any way to do it. In jinja2 we can use {{ variable | safe }}. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), this possible to you set HTML from code.

For example, you could do this:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return { __html: "<h1>This</h1>" };
}

function App() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank You let me check if this worls